# Model database csv bulk insertion from zip file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zip, activerecord-import

Need to import csv data inside a zip file to my product model using activerecord-import and rubyzip gem.

This code works (download the zip and display the csv name)

```
desc "Import products data from web"
task import_product: :environment do
    url = "https://example.com"
    dir = "db/example_zip.zip"

    File.open(dir, "wb") do |f|
        f.write HTTParty.get(url).body
    end

    Zip::File.open(dir) do |zip|
        zip.each do |entry|
            entry.name
        end
    end
end
```

In the "zip.each loop" I tried this :

```
items = []
CSV.foreach(entry, headers: true) do |row|
  items << Item.new(row.to_h)
end
Item.import(items)
```

I have the following error
    TypeError: no implicit conversion of Zip::Entry into String

According this tutorial: https://mattboldt.com/importing-massive-data-into-rails/

What is the best way to refresh my product model data with this csv? Do I have to read the file into memory (entry.get_input_stream.read) or save the file then import it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The exception `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Zip::Entry into String` raised because `CSV.foreach` method accepts a file path (which is a `String` object) as argument but you send it a `Zip::Entry` object instead.

You can simply extract the zip file and load its content directly into memory:

```
Zip::File.open(dir) do |zip|
  zip.each do |entry|
    items = []
    CSV.new(entry.get_input_stream.read, headers: true).each do |row|
      items << Item.new(row.to_h)
    end
    Item.import(items)
  end
end
```

Or if the csv file is too big, you can persist the decompressed files, then use `CSV.foreach` to load these files:

```
Zip::File.open(dir) do |zip|
  zip.each do |entry|
    csv_file = File.join(File.dirname(dir), entry.name)
    entry.extract(csv_file)
    items = []
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      items << Item.new(row.to_h)
    end
    Item.import(items)
  end
end
```

You can read more in these documentation:

- `CSV.foreach`: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach
- `rubyzip` gem https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#reading-a-zip-file

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here is my code to download a zip file and import data to my product model

```
require 'zip'
require 'httparty'
require 'active_record'
require 'activerecord-import'

namespace :affiliate_datafeed do
    desc "Import products data from Awin"
    task import_product_awin: :environment do
        url = "https://productdata.awin.com"
        dir = "db/affiliate_datafeed/awin.zip"

        File.open(dir, "wb") do |f| 
            f.write HTTParty.get(url).body
        end

        zip_file = Zip::File.open(dir)
        entry = zip_file.glob('*.csv').first
        csv_text = entry.get_input_stream.read
        products = []

        CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true).each do |row|
            products << Product.new(row.to_h)
        end
        Product.import(products)
  end
end
```

But the next question is, how to update the product db only if the product doesn't exist or if there is a new date in the last_updated field? What is the best way to refresh a large db?
Thanks